# How can I restrict keys in the used type?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I write a library

```
type State = {
  playing: boolean
  phases: {
    [key: string]: {
      progress: number
    }
  }
}

class BaseWidget {
  state: State

  constructor() {
    this.state = {
      playing: false,
      phases: {},
    }
  }
}
```

I use it like this

```
class Widget extends BaseWidget {
    constructor() {
        super()
        this.state.phases = {
            start: {
                progress: 0,
            },
            finish: {
                progress: 0,
            },
        }
    }
}
```

Different classes of inherited BaseWidget have different phases
How can I specify that this Widget class will only have a **start** and a **finish**?
Is it possible to somehow clarify the State type from the Widget class?
Or maybe I need to use generics?
Maybe I need to use not [key: string], but [key in keyof T]? But how do I pass T? What is the correct syntax?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use an [index signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures) to restrict the type of the keys, but you can use the `Record` utility type to get the same result. Because you're initializing `phases` with `{}` initially, you'll need to make it a `Partial<Record<...>>`:

```
type State<T extends string> = {
  playing: boolean
  phases: Partial<Record<T, {
    progress: number
  }>>
}

class BaseWidget<T extends string> {
  state: State<T>

  constructor() {
    this.state = {
      playing: false,
      phases: {},
    }
  }
}

type WidgetPhase = 'start' | 'finish'

class Widget extends BaseWidget<WidgetPhase> {
    constructor() {
        super()
        this.state.phases = {
            start: {
                progress: 0,
            },
            finish: {
                progress: 0,
            },
            nonexistent: { // Compile error!
                progress: 0,
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAysCGwIB4AqUIA8kDsAmAzlAcAE4CWOA5gHxQC8UA3gFBRRgA28IlVAXFABGAexGcI8HGw4ALeAQgFBABXilg5eJ2QAlCAGMRpPGgA0zGezCkRVUkuVQcAVwC2QiKRkBfGjRYfFhYDbgIiACEFCAB1cjwqCGA0DGwIfCISCmo6VnYSRAhBOEK0AJkjHCyXA2BjAAoASkt2dmBZcgIAOgKkBhbW625eakEAM21FMytWsHlFJyYfacGg9iCgllBIKDiEpJV56EYAcgKNE6gAHygTscpO2RPg0IUiPcTgVNxCKCjFD5JZCA4CHaK5GaVaq1BrNPKDVoEFyQUhNGaDdqdHoIJBdObRIiMeEIhHnYCCYkkqk2OwOcKCAAMKypq2ZLPY9xwjwp6PZ1ls9kcjLZ7OWvJJOBEOCwnVw5OYUAA9IqoABhERuMDkCQYUi2UgAQnF7JpgvpUCZxtWxrWrQ2LCAA)

If you don't actually want it to be `Partial`, you can initialize it through the constructor of the base class; this guarantees that all keys are always present:

```
type Phase = {
    progress: number
}

type State<T extends string> = {
  playing: boolean
  phases: Record<T, Phase>
}

class BaseWidget<T extends string> {
  state: State<T>

  constructor(phases: Record<T, Phase>) {
    this.state = {
      playing: false,
      phases: phases,
    }
  }
}

type WidgetPhase = 'start' | 'finish'

class Widget extends BaseWidget<WidgetPhase> {
    constructor() {
        super({
            start: {
                progress: 0,
            },
            finish: {
                progress: 0,
            },
        })
    }
}
```

[playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBACgFgQwM7QLxQN4Cgq6mAJwHsBzAiJJALigDsBXAWwCMICsBfLLUSKAZWAJgEADwAVKBAAeI2gBMkUJMAIBLWiQB8UdNlxgANghAaSNZkSKGICWjnyIU1KACUIAYyIF5EgDSwThBanNwexpRQAELIEADqavIkEMASUrIQCkoq6po6+spCIjSCwmLiIQ5etDn0HsDeABRgQS7uXj7+gbFaAJSYDrjAcGpIAHQqZboDeHhGJmY0AGYIhih+g3OtNC2xSBuzXLhcXDzg0AlJKfCx0wDkkwTAd1AAPlB3SxqjcHdhEUpLslgOk5IporEgSlRFDgDcUPlNtVavUmv0CrNcEh6JACI0MZjZo9gDQCYTCYRSORKDQAAwHcmHBmM3BfWg-UmbFlzYhkCguelc8kcZmYji9TYnLBAA)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I liked the second option more, although I will have to correct my code a little. But there is one mistake that I do not know how to solve. Can't use phase.progress on BaseWidget. Will you help me? [playground link](https://inlnk.ru/goJl7)

Comment: Looks like type inference doesn't do much on `Object.values`. Not sure how to solve this without a cast: `(phase as Phase).progress`.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a bit broad, but looking at what you're trying to achieve, I would create something like this:

```
type State = Record<string, any>;

class BaseWidget<S extends State> {
  state: S;

  constructor(initState: S) {
    this.state = initState;
  }
}

interface HasStartPhase {
  start: {
    progress: number;
  };
}

interface HasFinishPhase {
  finish: {
    progress: number;
    extraInfo: string;
  };
}

interface WidgetState extends State {
  playing: boolean;
  phases: HasStartPhase & HasFinishPhase;
}

class Widget extends BaseWidget<WidgetState> {
  constructor() {
    super({
      playing: false,
      phases: {
        start: {
          progress: 0
        },
        finish: {
          progress: 0,
          extraInfo: "abc"
        }
      }
    });
  }
}
```

It allows any state in your BaseWidget, and specific Widgets can specify their own State shape. Creating interfaces for the Phases allows you to mix and match them when they are needed.

Here is a [TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAysCGxoF4oCUIGMD2AnAJgDwDOwuAlgHYDmANFPJSAHwDcAsAFBeYA28xYlABCAiAHVy+ahGCEYUCAA8klfELiIIzKAG8uUKKS0AuWB26dDOSqVwBXTMDwAKKuWCakZmAEo9BoZQwAAW5MQAdMZIUKjunghIFoYAvlxpllRIuABm8JjQABICmrjAAAohYgFWRghlZvq1hmC42NS4EIJmlPYAtgBGELjJUCkWGVxZw3kFUMXEAGLuxCGV1U2GOSshjYEtbR1dxD39QyP7iiq48ACSlDnYZnZU1KPj6VxTlNmz0JLSWReaDKVTqWCJaCbKBgfggV5mAbYbC8CCMUZgKrELpmBalCpY6AAMnmAmWlHCa0JEy+nD4AiEAJkwCuYKEomxTNkhC5CS0OmhNjsjmcuBc-mhhmI9kgYslQVh8HhNDMeV42NolxahJONSC+rq8AaeoN+ta7U63SgAAYtUEUprmgbthTVnsnabzUcrdbHab9aCbvdHmYAETwAaYUN21J2jL6lK+d6fThAA) for you to try it out.